# Apply tax based on payment info

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-methods

I need to apply a custom tax over order based on informations provided on 'Payment Info' section, when using my custom payment method.
The problem seems the call stack, the informations are collected in Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::assignData, but the tax/discount can be applied in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract::collect.

There's a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a custom total and then check the payment method from the quote.

The below code was tested on Magento 1.9.3.1. and a 9.99 custom tax was applied to any order which used the Check/Money Order.

You just need to change the payment method in the method "collect" and the amount you want to add as a custom tax amount.

File: app/code/local/Colin/Core/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Colin_Core>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Colin_Core>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <colin_core>
                <class>Colin_Core_Model</class>
            </colin_core>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <colin_core>
                <class>Colin_Core_Block</class>
            </colin_core>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <colin_core>
                <class>Colin_Core_Helper</class>
            </colin_core>
        </helpers>

        <!-- Add custom tax total -->
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <custom_tax>
                        <class>colin_core/total</class>
                        <after>subtotal,shipping</after>
                        <before>tax</before>
                    </custom_tax>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

File: app/code/local/Colin/Core/Model/Total.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Colin_Core_Model_Total
 *
 * @extends     Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
 * @category    Colin
 * @package     Colin_Core
 */
class Colin_Core_Model_Total extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return "9.99";
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function getPaymentMethod()
    {
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment $payment */
        $payment = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getPayment();

        try {
            $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
        } catch (Exception $e ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $method->getCode();
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);
        if (($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping')) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->getPaymentMethod() !== 'checkmo') {
            return false;
        }

        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
        $price = $store->convertPrice("9.99");
        $basePrice = $store->convertPrice("9.99");
        $address->setCustomTaxAmount($price);
        $address->setCustomTaxBaseAmount($basePrice);
        $this->_addAmount($price);
        $this->_addBaseAmount($basePrice);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
     */
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $amount = $address->getCustomTaxAmount();
        if ($amount == 0) {
            return $address;
        }

        $title = Mage::helper('colin_core')->__('Custom Tax');
        $address->addTotal(
            array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => $title,
                'value' => $amount
            )
        );
        return $address;
    }
}
```

Attached is the custom tax applying to the order with check money order and not applying to the order with credit card payment method.

[image]

[image]